# My JavaScript functionr runs twice when I click on it once?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web-applications

I'm using Angular for my web app in a div tag I use ng-click to run a function for changing the value of a check box but when I click on div it runs twice.
This my HTML:

```
enter code here
<div class="switch" ng-click="f_changeSwitch(a_Order.isInSaloon)">
                                <label>
                                   
                                    <span>{{lang==1  ? 'سالن' : 'Saloon'}}</span>
                                    <input  ng-model="a_Order.isInSaloon" type="checkbox"><span class="lever lever_c"></span>
                                    {{lang==1  ? 'بیرون بر' : 'Take Away'}}

                                </label>
                            </div>
```

And this is my JavaScript

```
 $scope.f_changeSwitch = function (saloon) {
        console.log("counter", counter);
        console.log("saloon", saloon);
        console.log("$scope.a_Order.isInSaloon", $scope.a_Order.isInSaloon);
        if ($scope.a_Order.isInSaloon == true) {
            $scope.a_Order.isInSaloon = false;

        } else {
            $scope.a_Order.isInSaloon = true;
        }
        if ($scope.a_Order.isInSaloon == false) {
                $scope.packAge_Cost = {};
                $scope.packAge_Cost.a_tProductId_packageCost = $scope.a_tProductId_packageCost;
                $scope.packAge_Cost.t = $scope.a_prName;
                $scope.packAge_Cost.a_prName_EN = $scope.a_prName_EN;
                $scope.packAge_Cost.total = $scope.packAgeCostInNumber;
                $scope.ordered_item.push($scope.packAge_Cost)
                $scope.a_invTotal = $scope.a_invTotal + $scope.packAgeCost
                $scope.a_invTotalString = f_Cash2String($scope.a_invTotal);
             
            console.log("$scope.packAgeCost1234", $scope.packAgeCost);
        } else {
            $scope.a_invTotal = $scope.a_invTotal - $scope.packAgeCost; 
            $scope.a_invTotalString = f_Cash2String($scope.a_invTotal);
            console.log("is in saloon is true now")

        }
        counter++
    }
```

and this my logs, when I click once as you can see counter is 2
[image]

Comment: Without providing a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, it is hard for anyone to help troubleshoot this without guessing

Answer (score 0):

i found why it's run twice and it's because in html checkbox every time that i click on it it change the value and after it in js ng-click runs and it change the value too so i delete if condition in my function